# How to disconnect bluetooth in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to disconnect bluetooth by using

```
if (bluetoothAdapter != null) {
    if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()|bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        bluetoothAdapter.disable();
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    } 
}
```

But it is not working.Can anyone suggest something on that which will be fruitful for me.

Comment: What is not working? Disabling BT/canceling discovery takes some time, so it may not immediately show an effect, but will be completed later.

Comment: your if statement should have the logical OR - ||

Answer (score 0):

If you are disconnecting you should try and disconnect your specific connection rather than turning off bluetooth.. turning off will cause other active connections (which you might not have created also to disconnect)
If this is what you want i.e to disconnect every thing, then in the code above you should first cancel Discovery then Disable.
To do both of these you need the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN privilege.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.This is working fine after giving  BLUETOOTH_ADMIN privilege.But I need something different mean after disable bluetooth the user should not be able to enable it again.

Comment: pls accept / vote up the answer if it answered your original question